# Adjusting lidar data for tide

Tags: lidar, satellite-image

I'm using Lidar data collected over water to validate water depth estimates from satellite image. Vertical datum is NAVD83 but I have transformed it to mean sea level. Do I still need to account for tidal difference between the lidar and actual water level when the lidar was collected?